# Django Rest Framework Get Additional related fields in one to many relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

Here's the problem Products have multiple sizes which is many to many relation

**Products**

```
|-------|---------|
|   ID  |  Title  |
|-------|---------|
```

**Sizes**

```
|-------|---------|
|   ID  |  Title  |
|-------|---------|
```

**Size Through**

```
|------|--------------|-----------|---------|
|  ID  |  Product ID  |  Size ID  |  Stock  |
|------|--------------|-----------|---------|
```

I manage to get sizes in my product api using Django Rest Framework but i don't know how to get stock information as well.
here is the code I've

```
class SizeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
        )
        model = Size



class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sizes = SizeSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'url',
            'id',
            'title',
            "sizes",
        )
        model = Products
```

I would appreciate any help in this problem

**Models**

```
class Products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(Size, blank=True, through='SizeThrough')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Products'
        verbose_name = 'Product'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class SizeThrough(models.Model):
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=1)

class Size(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Can you add relevant models ?

Comment: You can read this：http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Comment: @JPG just added models

Comment: @Hayden I've gone through many times what i only found **"ManyToManyFields with a Through Model"** which is last section but i don't give more information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get `Size` through `SizeThrough`(you are trying the opposite):

```
class SizeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
        )
        model = Size


class SizeThroughSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    size = SizeSerializer()
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'stock',
            'size',
        )
        model = SizeThrough


class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sizes_info = SizeThroughSerializer(source='sizethrough_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'url',
            'id',
            'title',
            "sizes_info",
        )
        model = Products
```

Comment: This is what i got from this "Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `sizes_info` on serializer `ProductsSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Products` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Products' object has no attribute 'Sizethrough_set'."

Comment: just updated the answer change to `source='sizethrough_set'`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this. Maybe it works

```
class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sizes = SizeSerializer(many=True)
    stock = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_stock(self, obj):
         return[(x.stock, x.size) for x in SizeThrough.objects.filter(product=obj)]

    class Meta:
        fields = (
        'url',
        'id',
        'title',
        "sizes",
        "stock",
    )
        model = Products
```